# Dynamic Column Alias Name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way where I could set the column alias name as dynamic
DDL

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(20),
PRODUCT_PRICE INT );


INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ('COKE',20);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ('PEPSI',10);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ('FANTA',30);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ('COKE',30);
```

NOW

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_NAME,'COKE',PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_PRICE)) AS SSS
FROM PRODUCTS
```

would result in

```
SSS
50
```

and

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, ROWNUM AS RANK FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

results in

```
COKE
```

I would like to replace sss with coke but from a dynamic perspective that if the value is changed in the database so would the alias

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_NAME,'COKE',PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_PRICE)) AS
(
   SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM 
   (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, ROWNUM AS RANK FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
)
FROM PRODUCTS
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87db8/6 FIDDLE

Comment: you can use replace function

Comment: first of all, you shouldn't use `rownum` since it doesn't guaranteed, that it will be, what you would expect to be the first row. Second, what is your statement, exactly supposed to do? why do you use `sum(decode`?

Comment: It's Simple I just would like to rename the column alias dynamically without using 'COKE'

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIVOT to achieve the same.

If you want to use a sub-query instead of values for Product_name
 use PIVOT XML(Note the result will be in XML in this case)

For more information please check the below link

[PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators in Oracle 11g](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

```
with prod as (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, product_price FROM PRODUCTS)
     select *
     from  prod
     pivot  (sum(product_price) 
            for (product_name) in
            ('COKE' as COKE
          , 'FANTA' as FANTA
          , 'PEPSI' as PEPSI ))
```

**EDIT 1:-** You can also select only a particular drink like below

```
     with prod as (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, product_price FROM PRODUCTS)
     select COKE
     from  prod
     pivot  (sum(product_price) 
            for (product_name) in
            ('COKE' as COKE
          , 'FANTA' as FANTA
          , 'PEPSI' as PEPSI ))
```

Comment: Could you share a fiddle, the question is what if COKE changes to SPRITE?

Comment: updated the answer if you need Sprite then you need to use PIVOT XML

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamic query means you create a dynamic statement and then execute.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209615/oracle-dynamic-queries) is an example, use if else for this.

For your query change like this.

```
declare
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  sql_query varchar2(4000);
begin
  sql_query := 'select 1 as value from dual';
  open l_cursor for sql_query;
end;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102

Comment: This is not what I am looking at, I would like the actual alias name which is presented on the column heading to be dynamic